# Is there a freely usable map of Earth cave systems and/or density?

Tags: geography, open-data, database

I am considering creating some sort of model of the Earth using real world collected data. Things like worldwide height maps certainly exist, as do many maps of minerals, rainfall, etc.

Are there worldwide data available on underground cave systems?

By density, I mean the likelihood of there being a cave in a certain place, given coordinates. Hence it does not have to be exact (although this would be better), but a mathematical model or approximation would be useful if the former does not exist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might like to check [World Cave List](http://www-sop.inria.fr/agos/sis/DB/countries.html) which has a pretty extensive list of caves, their depths, and lengths.

For example:

> This list has been automatically produced from our World Caves Database.
>
> *Total depth and length of all caves currently collected in the database:*
>
> - Number of caves = 2424
> - Caves deeper than 300m = 1075
> - Caves longer than 3kms = 1628
> - Cumulated depth = 648 932 m
> - Cumulated length = 17 930 192 m

Comment: Great find, you beat my googling! The only thing I would improve in an ideal world would be lat long locations rather than just by country. I'll leave this for a little bit before accepting, to see if anyone else is aware of a better source. Thanks!

Comment: Their database has more info http://www-sop.inria.fr/agos/sis/DB/database.html  but I don't see lat/long.

Comment: The project behind the World Cave List seems to have gone quiet... Is there anyone out there that might want to pick up the project? I could host a new location for the database...